# Getting selected value for radio button

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" id="myRadio">Red color

<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the radio button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myRadio").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Basic example of getting value from radio button from w3schools. In the above example I need to get the display value.

for eg.,
I need `Red color`

not the value `red`.
[Example here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_radio_value)

Comment: What do you mean by "Red color"? Do you want the string: "Red color"?

Comment: Yes the string Red color

Comment: So set the value to "Red color" instead of "red".

Comment: @j08691 It's not about red color. How can I get that text value from it?

Comment: By setting the value attribute to "Red color" instead of "red".  `<input type="radio" name="colors" value="Red color" id="myRadio">`

Comment: The `Red color` string is not part of the `input` tag. The input tag is self closing, meaning: it ends at `<input ...id="myRadio">`. So the string cannot be accessed using the `input` tag handle

Comment: @surajck Thanks for this..I understood..Deleting my question now

Comment: @sagarkaware surajck's answer is not correct, it is in the sense that the string is not actually associated with the `input` but that doesn't mean you can't find it. Answers below

Answer (score 2):

Rather than wrapping just the text in the label, make it *useful*

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" id="myRadio" />
    Red Colour
</label>
```

Now your code can do this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var radio = document.getElementById("myRadio"),
        label = radio.parentNode,
        text = (label.textContent || label.innerText).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

This will get the parent of the radio button (the label), gets its text content, strip spaces before and after it, and output the result: `Red Colour`.

For bonus points, you can now click on the "Red Colour" text to select the radio button. Usability awesomeness!

Much better.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap that text in a `label` to help target it and find the `.innerHTML` of `.nextElementSibling`

```
var x = document.getElementById("myRadio").nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m0fbqs31/)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the text in a label tag, and then use `nextSibling.innerHTML` to get the text inside the label.

Add the label:

```
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="red" id="myRadio" /><label>Red color</label>
```

Then use `nextSibling.innerHTML` instead of `value`:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myRadio").nextSibling.innerHTML;
```